# Checking if site is overloaded

Tags: php, apache

I've seen some sites that display a message to say that they are "overloaded". Do not know if this is the connection to the DB being maxed out.

Is this done programatically ? Or through a server setting ?

Comment: And we're supposed to know how each site does this? Perhaps there's a "areyouoverloaded.com" site that pounds on the sites until they stop responding, at which point they dispatch a letter via USPS priority mail to notify the site admins that they should log into a system and change their page over to the overloaded version. Or perhaps there's some code that monitors the average SQL query duration and automatically toggles over to overloaded when execution time exceeds 0.5s

Comment: Sorry to see you having a bad day @Marc B and was not aware I was stepping into a minefield here. I'm just asking a simple question. The tags should give enough context. If there's no conventional way of doing so then just say so.

Comment: it's a bit of clueless question for a user with your profile don't you think? It would've helped if you could've provided an example.

Comment: I really didn't get it, `overloaded` ?

Comment: @Simon_eQ Difficult to do so as the sites where I've seen this are available most of the time.

Comment: [This link might help you](http://spicefuse.com/server-overloading-explained-t-2.html). I think it is mostly pragmatically, perhaps by a custom server or server modification. My guess is that it's a matter of limiting connections to your website after stress-testing what your hardware can handle.

Comment: @SheikhHeera That's what the message says. Am assuming that this is either the result of too many connections to the DB or some other factor linked to the number of users.

Comment: How can I reformulate this question ?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking this would be usually be a load balancer setting, rather than something you code directly into your application. The load balancer occasionally checks the health of your servers for your site, and routes traffic to a different server/site if it detects they're unavailable or have high-latency, etc.

Coding it into your application would mean that if your server is under heavy load and the application is slowing down, the code to check if it's overloaded would also be slowing down. If that makes sense.

**Edit:**
To expand a little on how this is done with a load balancer, you would generally have a page in your application that runs some basic checks and returns a HTTP 200 if everything is OK, or a HTTP 503 if things aren't OK. The load balancer would then hit that URL on your server and check the response code to see if it's up or down (how often it checks is something you can configure). If it's up, cool. If it's down, it will start sending traffic somewhere else.

Since you control the check page, you can write the check(s) however you want. Usually you'll just have a few quick sanity checks in there. e.g. Try connecting to your database, if it gives you a "too many connections" error, then return a 503 and the load balancer will know you're overloaded.

If you only care about the database case and not things like server load or latency, you can achieve similar results by just catching any errors when connecting to your database, and redirecting users to a static page when that happens. For example,

```
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whatever", $user, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    header("Location: /site_overloaded_message.html"); exit();
}
```